# Regroup Multiprocessing Tasks under a single row (Windows 10 TaskManager)

Tags: multiprocessing, windows-10, monitoring, taskmanager

**Hello**,

I didn't know where to post such a question and I couldn't find anything on google about it, so here I am asking the best people to help me with solving this minor "issue";

I would like to know if is there a way to see how much, *Mozilla, Whatsapp or any other app that uses Multitasking*, how much resources they consume in the same time as if they were using a single process, here is an img to visualise

[image: TaskManager]

**Thank-you beforehand**.

Update: I have tried many alternatives for the TaskManager, even those who show the process under a tree, but they don't sum the total memory usage of all opened process, *(img isn't from my computer)*

[image: Tree view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello**, I will answer my own question,
a BIG KARMA, the problem has been solved today after Windows10 Update **(windows fall creators update)**

[image]

As you can see, the Multi Processing Apps are now Grouped in one window, which allow me to see how much each Process consumes, and how much they do all consume, which is MAGNIFICIENT, windows 10 did something great today, thanks ♥

**Issue Solved.**

PS: Thanks for the one who downvoted my question judging it NOT USEFUL, here even Microsoft answered you.